# Architecture compatibility issue: app made compatible with 64-bit stops working on iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Our app was recently upgraded to be compatible with 64-bit architectures (which required, besides changing Build Settings, upgrading several third-party libraries). However, it stopped working iOS 6 and I'm wondering if during the upgrade we unknowingly ditched the 32-bit compatibility.

I use Objective-C on Xcode 6.3 with the following Architecture Settings:
[image: Current architecture settings]

The app now runs on iOS 7+ without a problem but not on iOS 6 (device or Simulator).

I'd appreciate your advice on where else to look to resolve this. I think (and hoping) it is probably a matter of a setting in Build Settings.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I am using OSX 10.10.3.

When I run the app in Xcode (either 6.3 or 5.1.1) it says "iOS Simulator failed to install the application" immediately after Build is successful.

On iOS 6 device, the app crashes immediately and this is the message that shows on the screen:

```
Jul 18 12:07:57 UserX-iPhone com.apple.launchd
(UIKitApplication:com.theCompany.APPname[0x196d][1687]) <Notice>:
(UIKitApplication:com.theCompany.Appname[0x196d]) Job failed to exec(3)
```

for weird reason: 13

I hope this helps.

**Edit 2:**

Please see following screenshot from Xcode Device Console Log. Testing took place on iPhone 3, iOS 6.1.6.

[image]

Comment: A comment about the above image: **Latest iOS** is shown to be **7.1** since the screenshot was taken in Xcode 5.1.1 (I downloaded the Xcode 5.1.1 so to test the app in the iOS 6 Simulator). In Xcode 6.3 the setting is **iOS 8.3**.

Comment: What OSX do you use? And what xcode says, when you try to run app on ios 6 device.

Comment: Thanks @nyekimov! OSX 10.10.3.  And Xcode says "iOS Simulator failed to install the application" immediately after Build is successful. On iOS 6 device, the app crashes immediately and this is the message that shows on the screen:
Jul 18 12:07:57 UserX-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1]
(UIKitApplication:com.theCompany.APPname[0x196d][1687]) <Notice>:
(UIKitApplication:com.theCompany.Appname[0x196d]) Job failed to exec(3)
for weird reason: 13
I hope this helps.

Comment: OSX 10.10.3 does not support ios 6 simulators. Please, print XCODE message as it is in your question or better to attach a screenshot, it definitely gives more information about the issue.

Comment: Thanks again @nyekimov! Please see the edit in my question above. It is actually my colleague who received this message while testing. I'll ask him to take a screenshot and send it to me.

Comment: @nyekimov, re. your comment on OSX 10.10.3 not supporting iOS 6 simulators. This explains why I had no luck in installing iOS 6 simulator in Xcode 5.1.1 ("Package cannot be trusted" !) but iOS 6.1 simulator installed without a problem.

Comment: @nyekimov, please see my 2nd edit. I've added a screenshot of the error message (copy and pasted from Xcode's Device Console Log).

Comment: my iOS simulator 6 behaves the same way as yours, but it happens, because OSX 10.10 does not support iOS 6, even if you add simulator manually. However, I am able to test apps on device with iOS 6. Your problem seems to be about rights. Try to restart machine and device and then try again. But do not try to run iOS 6 simulator on that machine, may be broken simulator causes the issue with device.

Comment: Point taken, @nyekimov. Thanks! I will do more testing.

Comment: @nyekimov your suggestion worked. Thank you! If you it as an answer, I will select it the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my iOS simulator 6 behaves the same way as yours, but it happens, because OSX 10.10 does not support iOS 6, even if you add simulator manually. However, I am able to test apps on device with iOS 6. Your problem seems to be about rights. Try to restart machine and device and then try again. But do not try to run iOS 6 simulator on that machine, may be broken simulator causes the issue with device.

Comment: We also needed to re-install the app (after restarting the device) and then it worked.